# How to use collection_check_boxes together with serialized Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization, checkbox, view-helpers

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :blocked_user_ids, Array
end
```

View:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:category, :blocked_user_ids, User.all, :id, :full_name) %>
```

The id of a blocked user is stored in the serialized attribute `blocked_user_ids`.

Passing checked/unchecked boxes for all users with [collection_check_boxes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) to the controller works perfectly.

I wonder though how to show a checked box for each id that is stored in the `blocked_user_ids` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= collection_check_boxes(:category, :blocked_user_ids, User.all, :id, :full_name) %>`

would then become

```
# Probably NOT a good idea to interate through all Users!
- User.all.each do |user|
  # assuming user has a `name` attribute
  %label
    = check_box_tag "category[blocked_user_ids][]",
      value = "#{user.id}",
      checked = (@category.block_user_ids.include? user.id.to_s),
      id: "blocked_user_ids_#{user.id}"
    "#{user.name}"
```

Comment: I didn't test this code, so there might be some typos, feel free to let me know if it's not working and I can fix it.